# Mining overlapping orthogonal clusters from high dimensional data

Tags: embeddings, clustering

What are the recommended strategies for identifying overlapping and somewhat orthogonal clusters in a large, high-dimensional dataset?

As an illustration, consider a dataset comprised of various recipes represented as text embeddings. I'm looking for an approach that would result in overlapping clusters, such as those associated with different cuisines, meal types (e.g., soup, main course, dessert), and other categories (like vegetarian dishes).

To clarify, the expectation isn't to obtain these precise clusters or to segregate them into orthogonal groups, this is just a general example. Of course, in the real dataset, I would not be able to specify the clusters I expect (e.g. as labels) upfront.

I'm unsure about what objective I should be optimizing in this context. I'd appreciate any guidance or insights!